# Import Math shows unused import statement

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

When I try to import math on a new pc with Pycharm, I get the message "unused import statement 'import math'", Python 3.8 is the interpreter.
Sorry I am pretty new to Python and I know this is fairly basic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unused import statement 'import requests' in PyChram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64838032/unused-import-statement-import-requests-in-pychram)

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm this appears due to import inspection and if you have imported a module and have not used that module in your code, it will show a warning like this to avoid unnecessary imports.

Answer (score 0):

The message "unused import statement 'import math'" isn't itself an error. It just tells you that you are not using any function from the math library in your program.

If you are actually using functions from that library, and they do not get recognized and you get the error ' "unresolved reference ...", you're probably forgetting to add 'math.' before the function you're using. For instance:

```
sin(x) #is wrong
math.sin(x) #is correct
```